# Httpd problem, suspect an attack but not sure

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, netstat, connections

On one of my servers when I type netstat -n I get a huge output, something like 400 entries for httpd.  The bandwidth on the server isn't high, so I'm confused as to what's causing it.  I'm suspecting an attack, but not sure.

Intermittently, the web server will stop responding. When this happens all other services such as ping, ftp, work just normally.  System load is also normal.

The only thing that isn't normal I think is the "netstat -n" output.

Can you guys take a look and see if there's something I can do?  I have APF installed, but not sure what rules I should put into place to mitigate the problem.

Btw, I'm running CentOS 5 Linux with Apache 2.

```
root@linux [/backup/stuff/apf-9.7-1]# netstat -n|grep :80
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:48397        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           218.86.49.153:1734          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:48316          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           208.80.193.33:54407         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           65.49.2.180:46768           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           120.0.70.180:9414           FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.101:43386       TIME_WAIT    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.92:80           220.181.7.112:51601         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.94:80           220.181.94.215:53097        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.188.236:53203       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:62297       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:64345       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.115.105:36600        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           118.77.25.129:1743          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:35107        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:61801       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           66.249.69.155:57641         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1009 120.136.23.56:80           114.249.218.24:17204        CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           119.235.237.85:45355        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           217.212.224.182:45195       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.189.10.170:1556         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.102:35701       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           118.77.25.129:1745          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           118.77.25.129:1749          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           118.77.25.129:1748          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.195.76.250:26635        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.111.239:58417        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.218.116.164:53370        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.236:56168        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           120.136.23.93:36947        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1009 120.136.23.56:80           114.249.218.24:16991        CLOSING     
tcp        0    305 120.136.23.56:80           59.58.149.147:1881          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           61.186.48.148:1405          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.125.66.46:26703         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4814          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           218.86.49.153:1698          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4813          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4810          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.236:60508        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4811          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.125.71:43991        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.125.71:52182        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4806          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.125.71:56024        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4805          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.89.251.167:2133         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:48340          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:63543       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:39544        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.125.71:48066        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4822          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.113.253:55817        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.141.124.130:11316       FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4820          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4816          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.140:40743       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.125.71:60979        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29255         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           117.36.231.149:4078         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29251         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           117.36.231.149:4079         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29260         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.236:51379        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           114.237.16.26:1363          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29263         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:63106        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.101:45795       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.224.115.203:46315       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           66.249.69.5:35081           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           203.209.252.26:51590        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29268         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           216.7.175.100:54555         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.92:80           220.181.7.38:47180          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:64467       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29265         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.92:80           220.181.7.110:46593         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29276         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           117.36.231.149:4080         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           117.36.231.149:4081         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:50215          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0 101505 120.136.23.56:80           111.166.41.15:1315          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29274         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4878          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      1 120.136.23.93:80           58.33.226.66:4715           FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4877          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   1009 120.136.23.56:80           114.249.218.24:17062        CLOSING     
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29280         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4874          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           124.115.0.28:59777          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4872          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4870          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:50449          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.84.58.254:4868          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.107:37579       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.114.238:34255        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.105:35530       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:43960        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.111.229:41667        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.220:52669        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.111.239:56779        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        1  16560 120.136.23.56:80           210.13.118.102:43675        CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0   1009 120.136.23.56:80           114.249.218.24:17084        CLOSING     
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.105:33501       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           123.116.230.132:9703        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:49414          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.168.66.48:3360          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.168.66.48:3361          FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.168.66.48:3362          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           66.249.68.183:39813         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:51569          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           216.129.119.11:58377        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.111.229:41914        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.213.146.54:33921         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:50287          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           61.150.84.6:2094            TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.218.116.166:33262        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.101:38064       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           110.75.167.223:39895        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.99:48991          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        1  16560 120.136.23.56:80           210.13.118.102:61893        CLOSE_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           61.152.250.144:42832        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.174:37484       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:63403       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           119.119.247.249:62121       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           66.249.69.155:62189         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.80:60303        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    363 120.136.23.56:80           123.89.153.157:39067        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80                127.0.0.1:49406             TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.92:80           66.249.65.226:61423         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.136.173.33:19652        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   2332 120.136.23.56:80           221.180.12.66:29243         LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.136.173.33:19653        FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5061          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.179.90:51318        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5060          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:54333        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      1 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5062          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:42547        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.125.66.135:39557        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5057          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17012         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17013         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           222.190.105.186:4641        FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5059          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17014         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64078         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5058          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17015         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64079         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17016         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.113.224:53092        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      1 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5065          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5064          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5067          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5066          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:58200          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  27544 120.136.23.56:80           124.160.125.8:8189          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.125.66.27:30477         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.102:60019       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64080         FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:37673        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  26136 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64081         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.127.20.37:17002         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64082         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64083         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64084         FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           60.169.49.238:64085         FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4084          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4085          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4086          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:42269        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56911        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56910        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4081          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.221:34606        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4082          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:25451          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4083          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.100:55875       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.100:51522       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.9.9.224:49650           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4088          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4089          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18753        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18752        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18755        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           66.249.69.2:43954           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18754        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.231:48903        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           121.0.29.194:61655          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56915        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56914        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:16247          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56913        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:59909        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:48389        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           125.238.149.46:56912        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           222.190.105.186:4635        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.106:44326       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.170.217.26:1812         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.170.217.26:1810         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.104:36898       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:39033        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.231:58229        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.170.217.26:1822         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.170.217.26:1820         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           121.206.183.172:2214        FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.221:54341        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           222.170.217.26:1818         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18751        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18750        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           61.177.143.210:4226         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           116.9.9.250:55700           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  39599 120.136.23.93:80           125.107.166.221:3083        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           120.86.215.180:62554        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.100:48442       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34199       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  69227 120.136.23.93:80           125.107.166.221:3084        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.231:53605        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34196       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           120.86.215.180:62556        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34203       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.104:40252       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34202       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18731        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34201       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34200       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.9.9.224:49538           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.57:49229        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           124.224.63.144:18734        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.150.182.221:34204       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.72.156.95:2517          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:59728        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           116.20.61.208:50598         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5031          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5030          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.191.255.196:46290       FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5037          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      1 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5036          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           115.56.48.140:38058         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5039          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           115.56.48.140:38057         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5038          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:45862          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5033          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5032          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5034          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.9.9.224:49582           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.221:38777        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.125.66.15:27007         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           67.195.37.98:59848          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5040          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:14651          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.221:58495        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.72.156.95:2765          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5053          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           120.86.215.180:62578        ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.179.58:36715        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           122.86.41.132:5048          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           61.153.27.172:4889          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.72.156.95:1995          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.9.9.224:49501           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0  12270 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49551           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   6988 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49550           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           66.249.67.106:60516         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.179.76:56301        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.178.41:32907        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           61.153.27.172:24811         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.155:35617       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:50081        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   3650 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49555           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           116.9.9.250:55632           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0   4590 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49554           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    823 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49553           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0    778 120.136.23.56:80           119.12.4.49:49552           ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0  31944 120.136.23.93:80           222.67.49.170:52229         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           219.219.127.2:44661         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.102:38602       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           61.177.143.210:4208         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           117.23.111.2:3297           TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.72.156.95:2079          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.92:80           220.181.7.49:44133          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.80:80           125.46.48.20:38627          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    660 120.136.23.56:80           113.16.37.24:62908          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.231:62850        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.235:33423        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           216.129.119.40:53331        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           116.248.65.32:2580          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           61.177.143.210:4199         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           125.107.166.221:3052        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           216.7.175.100:36933         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      1 120.136.23.56:80           183.35.149.94:2414          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0  26963 120.136.23.56:80           124.160.125.8:8274          LAST_ACK    
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           61.153.27.172:16350         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:64907        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4116          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.102:32937       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           218.59.137.178:52731        FIN_WAIT2   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           123.125.66.53:31474         ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0   8950 120.136.23.56:80           221.194.136.245:21574       ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           216.7.175.100:36922         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           216.7.175.100:36923         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           221.130.177.106:41386       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.221:62681        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           111.72.156.95:1639          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4103          TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.231:44007        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           61.153.27.172:15026         TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           202.160.180.125:59521       TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0    660 120.136.23.56:80           113.16.37.24:62921          FIN_WAIT1   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           220.181.94.229:54767        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4148          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.93:80           202.104.103.210:2423        TIME_WAIT   
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.92.53:4149          ESTABLISHED 
tcp        0      0 120.136.23.56:80           219.131.
```

Comment: If this is your real IP address, you shouldn't have published it... It just don't feel right.

Comment: Have you had a look at the apache logs? Do you see anything unusual?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps you a bit:

```
# for i in $(sort /tmp/ips | uniq); do geoiplookup $i ;done | sort | uniq -c
  4 GeoIP Country Edition: AU, Australia
 83 GeoIP Country Edition: CN, China
 13 GeoIP Country Edition: --, N/A
  1 GeoIP Country Edition: NZ, New Zealand
  1 GeoIP Country Edition: SE, Sweden
 21 GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
```

I've seen that some are from "regular" spiders (baidu etc).

Answer (score 0):

Might be [Slowloris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowloris).

Comment: Wouldn't the sockets mainly be established for slowloris and not time_wait?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run something such as:

```
netstat -ntu | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It'll roughly tell you how many connections per IP which may make it easier to spot abuse / block them.

Answer (score 0):

What does `tail -f /var/log/httpd/access_log` tell you whenever that attack (or whatever) happens? Or, if you just read the log afterwards, what URL's did they hit?

Answer (score 0):

What is your MaxClients setting?  It sounds like you are reaching this setting.  When that happens, Apache stops serving requests one of the existing clients closes the connection.  Other services will continue to accept requests while this is happening.

If you have the server-status page enabled, you can see what the clients are doing in near real time.  However, I recommend locking the server-status down to just specific IP addresses or that you use some other form of authentication.

As far as the traffic from all these IP addresses, I usually rip through the access logs with Perl when I need to see where the traffic is coming from.  Since I don't have access to your logs, here is a quick and dirty Perl program that takes the output from your netstat command, and it performs recursive DNS look ups to try to determine where these IP addresses are coming from.  It expects to find the contents of your netstat in a file called "junk".

Hope this helps.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

our %iph = ();

sub recDNS ( $ ) {
    my $arpa = shift;

    $arpa =~ s/^\d+\.//;

    print "+++++ $arpa +++++\n";

    my $retVal = system ( "host", "-a", "$arpa" );
    if ( $retVal != 0 ) {
    recDNS ( $arpa );
    }
}

sub makeArpa ( $ ) {
    my $ip = shift;

    my @ipParts = split ( /\./, $ip );

    my $arpa = "";

    while ( $#ipParts > -1 ) {
    my $part = pop ( @ipParts );
    $arpa .= "$part.";
    }

    $arpa .= "in-addr.arpa";

    recDNS ( $arpa );
}

open ( RD, "junk" );

while ( <RD> ) {
    chomp;
    my @nparts = split ( /\s+/, $_ );

    my $ip = $nparts[4];
#    print "$_\n";

    $ip =~ s/:\d+$//;

#    print "$ip\n";

    $iph{$ip} = 0 unless ( defined ( $iph{$ip} ) );
    $iph{$ip}++;

}

close ( RD );

foreach my $ip (sort keys %iph) {
    print "----- $ip: count->$iph{$ip} -----\n";
    my $retVal = system ( "host", "-a", "$ip" );
    if ( $retVal != 0 ) {
    makeArpa ( $ip );
    }
}
```